# Caffe import working with python2 but not python2.7 / ipython notebook, despite both being 2.7.10?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython, caffe

I've successfully compiled the caffe library and the python module.

I can do this:

```
Jamess-Air:~ james$ python2 -V
Python 2.7.10
Jamess-Air:~ james$ python2
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 13 2015, 12:05:58) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import caffe
>>>
```

But, bizarrely, this fails:

```
Jamess-Air:~ james$ python2.7 -V
Python 2.7.10
Jamess-Air:~ james$ python2.7
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jun 19 2015, 15:39:31) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import caffe
Segmentation fault: 11
Jamess-Air:~ james$
```

I cannot understand this at all! Whenever I try to run using iPython notebook I get the same crash.

Any ideas as to what may be causing this, and how I might fix it, or at least get iPython Notebook to use the different python version so I can run this thing?

Thanks!

Comment: In your case `python2.7` and `python2` point to physically different interpreters of the same version. In one `caffe` was built successfully, in the other it is not. You can avoid all that confusion by using `python -m` syntax instead of command line scripts wherever possible. So instead of `pip install`, you can use `python -m pip install` and instead of `ipython` you can call `python -m IPython`, etc..

Comment: That's strange, can you do `which python2` and `which python2.7` to check if they are different interpreters, as @cel suggests?

Comment: @ThomasK, well the time when the interpreter was compiled/installed is different, so I assume they have to be different.

Comment: @cel good point, I didn't spot that. It may be that they're trying to load the same library, but its compilation/linking is only right for one of them.